# Wifi101 ad-hoc network

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

I've reviewed the WiFi101 library but have found no way to make the 101 an ad-hoc network.  Am I missing something?  I'd like to be able to emulate the RedFly example:
http://notebook.kulchenko.com/embedded/storing-wifi-configuration-in-eeprom-on-arduino

Can the 101 become an ad-hoc network?  I understand the security problem with the ad-hoc capability so it would make sense that Arduino prohibits it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can have an ad-hoc network, you can see the example on the github here: 
https://github.com/arduino-libraries/WiFi101/blob/master/examples/AP_SimpleWebServer/AP_SimpleWebServer.ino

It shows how to create an open ad-hoc network, for a secured one, you might need to check the datasheet + the method implement "beginAP".

Comment: It does not need to be secured.  Thank you!